# New app that will work on both iPhone 5 and older versions

Tags: ios5, ios6, iphone-5

So, I've been reading and reading up on the subject but nowhere has an exact answer for me. How can you make an app available for the iPhone5 and the earlier models? Do you simply have to have an iOS5 version and an iOS6 version?

Anything constructive helps, thanks guys.

Comment: Because OS updates come direct from Apple (rather than through a carrier), you can pretty much forget about supporting older iOS versions.  In my experience, the only people who don't update their iOS are the same cheapskates who don't buy apps.

Comment: So when im on xcode making an iOS6 app, how do I make it so that it supports the smaller screen size and the iPhone 5 screen size? because storyboard only lets me make the iPhone 5 screen size

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html

Comment: I've read that a few times already. I understand the iPhone/iPad things, but what do I do for a longer screen?

Comment: It's the same - you need to add a storyboard for each resolution you want to support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build an app using iOS 6 as the Base SDK and use the Auto Layout feature to make screens that can scale for all type of screens. You'll need Xcode 4.5 to do this.

Get started with Auto Layout here:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2
http://www.raywenderlich.com/20897/beginning-auto-layout-part-2-of-2

Other apps will also work on iPhone 5 but will have black bars on top and bottom.